# Record screen in X

Tags: software-rec, x11, video, screenshot

How can I record all activity on the screen for a certain amount of time? I know about tools like `xwd` that capture a still image; can they be extended to record video? I'd prefer not using any fancy debian tools or ImageMagick utilities

Answer (score 6):

You could try [xvidcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xvidcap/).

Answer (score 6):

http://live.gnome.org/Istanbul

- Graphical
- Friendly
- Complete

Answer (score 4):

What about a VNC based solution? Start a VNC session (via Xvnc or the builtin gnome/kde VNC tools). Then use [vnc2flv](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/vnc2flv/index.html), or the older vncrec or vnc2swf.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is the open-source Wink (http://www.debugmode.com/wink/). It is nowhere near as functional as Camtasia, but it runs on Windows and Linux. I have used it to create some small recordings, and it works reasonably well.

Comment: I must say it works, and in some ways it's better tool for making screencasts than pure recorders - even I am opponent of closed software and Flash player. But if someone don't mind about closedsource Flash, He/She might not mind about this tool :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ffmpeg`.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -qscale 0 -s wxga -r 25 -i :0.0 recording.mpg
```

Answer (score 0):

VMWare also includes screen recording capabilities. Are you working with a virtualized system?

Answer (score 0):

You can use www.screenr.com which is great for recording screen activity. The down side is that it posts directly to the internet or youtube, and I can't remember if it lets you download a copy of your recording. It requires Java. The quality produced is HD and you can also record with or without audio.

Screenr gives you a maximum of 5 minutes to record. They do have a premium option, though I have not used that so can't tell if that lets you record for longer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Debian or a Debian-based system, I recommend SimpleScreenRecorder.
To retrieve it, execute
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder`
and then execute `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder`.